Could not resolve dependencies: cabal cannot build snap framework project
I think one of the most common stuffs to build when learning a programming language is web app, so when learning Haskell, I decided to give Snap a try.
I'm on macOS Monterey (x64), didn't install GHC via Homebrew. Used ghcup, instead
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh

This is what I got when running ghcup tui
GHCup 0.1.22.0 (latest, recommended)
Stack 2.15.5 (recommended)
HLS 2.7.0.0 (recommended)
cabal 3.10.3.0 (latest,recommended)
GHC 9.8.2

Let's install snap:
$ cabal update
$ cabal install snap snap-templates

Then create a Snap project:
$ mkdir snapdtest
$ cd snaptest
$ snap init barebones
$ cabal install

Got these errors:
Error: cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: snaptest-0.1 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: bytestring (dependency of snaptest)
[__1] rejecting: bytestring-0.12.1.0/installed-ab96 (conflict: snaptest =>
bytestring>=0.9.1 && <0.11)
[__1] skipping: bytestring-0.12.1.0, bytestring-0.12.0.2, bytestring-0.12.0.1,
bytestring-0.12.0.0, bytestring-0.11.5.3, bytestring-0.11.5.2,
bytestring-0.11.5.1, bytestring-0.11.5.0, bytestring-0.11.4.0,
bytestring-0.11.3.1, bytestring-0.11.3.0, bytestring-0.11.2.0,
bytestring-0.11.1.0, bytestring-0.11.0.0 (has the same characteristics that
caused the previous version to fail: excluded by constraint '>=0.9.1 && <0.11'
from 'snaptest')
[__1] trying: bytestring-0.10.12.1
[__2] next goal: base (dependency of snaptest)
[__2] rejecting: base-4.19.1.0/installed-654f (conflict: bytestring =>
base>=4.2 && <4.16)
[__2] skipping: base-4.20.0.1, base-4.20.0.0, base-4.19.1.0, base-4.19.0.0,
base-4.18.2.1, base-4.18.2.0, base-4.18.1.0, base-4.18.0.0, base-4.17.2.1,
base-4.17.2.0, base-4.17.1.0, base-4.17.0.0, base-4.16.4.0, base-4.16.3.0,
base-4.16.2.0, base-4.16.1.0, base-4.16.0.0 (has the same characteristics that
caused the previous version to fail: excluded by constraint '>=4.2 && <4.16'
from 'bytestring')
[__2] rejecting: base-4.15.1.0, base-4.15.0.0, base-4.14.3.0, base-4.14.2.0,
base-4.14.1.0, base-4.14.0.0, base-4.13.0.0, base-4.12.0.0, base-4.11.1.0,
base-4.11.0.0, base-4.10.1.0, base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0,
base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1,
base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0,
base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2,
base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2,
base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from non-upgradeable package requires installed
instance)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, bytestring, snaptest)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: bytestring, base, snaptest

How to solve this?
Info added: my .cabal file:
Name:                snaptest
Version:             0.1
Synopsis:            Project Synopsis Here
Description:         Project Description Here
License:             AllRightsReserved
Author:              Author
Maintainer:          maintainer@example.com
Stability:           Experimental
Category:            Web
Build-type:          Simple
Cabal-version:       >=1.2

Executable snaptest
  hs-source-dirs: src
  main-is: Main.hs

  Build-depends:
    base                      >= 4     && < 5,
    bytestring                >= 0.9.1 && < 0.11,
    mtl                       >= 2     && < 3,
    snap-core                 >= 1.0   && < 1.1,
    snap-server               >= 1.0   && < 1.2

  if impl(ghc >= 6.12.0)
    ghc-options: -threaded -Wall -fwarn-tabs -funbox-strict-fields -O2
                 -fno-warn-unused-do-bind
  else
    ghc-options: -threaded -Wall -fwarn-tabs -funbox-strict-fields -O2


You can make it much easier for folks to reproduce your problem by including the .cabal file that snap init generates. Bonus points for cutting out parts that don't affect your problem.

After digging a little, it looks like it's probably this one.

As a first experiment, try cabal build --allow-newer. If that succeeds, then you can know that the following advice will eventually get you something that works.
My read of this is that snap init wrote a .cabal file with a bytestring dependency that's too strict/is out of date. From hackage, we can see that the latest snaps can work with bytestring-0.12.*, so try relaxing the dependency on bytestring (and possibly on snap) in the auto-generated file.
I reproduced your issue using this .cabal file. If you're using the same one, I also needed to update the cabal-version directive to 1.8; after that, it built with ghc-9.8.1 (the one I have installed, too lazy to try with ghc-9.8.2 but I'd be shocked if it worked on one but not the other). Here's the exact diff:
11c11
< Cabal-version:       >=1.2
---
> Cabal-version:       >=1.8
19c19
<     bytestring                >= 0.9.1 && < 0.11,
---
>     bytestring                >= 0.9.1 && < 0.12,


Whoa that works. I tried cabal run --allow-newer... didn't work because it's invalid command. So gotta edit the .cabal file, upgrade bytestring to 0.12, and run the usual cabal build and cabal run

@anta40 Strange. cabal run --allow-newer works just fine here. Can you double-check what you ran for typos? If there are none, what is the exact error you get? Also, cabal run should execute the build phase automatically for you, so you shouldn't need to cabal build before you cabal run.

Aaarghh silly me. I typed cabal run --alow-newer. Missing a "l". cabal run --allow-newer works fine. Guess I need a bit of coffee..
